# React Application SSO login issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-sign-on

I have a website integrated with SSO authentication. Login sets an SM cookie which is required for further HTTP calls.Issue i am facing is  when the SM cookie expires or closing and reopening the browser instance.I should ideally be redirecting the app to SSO login page but due to browser cache, it doesn't go to login page but keep coming back to application. I have no idea how to handle such scenario. If is use location.reload(true), it keeps on loading. If i try to redirect to login, it keeps on redirecting to login page. Below is the code snippet when my api returns result when it doesn't receive SM cookie.

```
  if (response.headers.get("content-type") && response.headers.get("content-type").indexOf("application/json") == -1) {
            console.log("reloading")
            window.location.reload(true); (trying to clear cache but not working)
            //Redirecting to login page
        }
```

Application behaves weird due to cookie cache issues.

What is the correct way to handle this.